# Translating a JPG + JGW to a JP2 File

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, jpeg-2000

I have a couple of files (one .jpg file and one .jgw file) that I would like to translate to a .jp2 file format. I need the .jp2 file format because the pipeline I'm working on uses that file format specifically. I've been trying to use gdal_translate:

```
os.system("gdal_translate -of VRT <input directory>.jpg <temp_directory>.vrt)
os.system("gdalwarp -of JP2OpenJPEG <temp_directory>.vrt <output_directory>.jp2)
```

I've seen a lot of links talk about translation from .jp2 to another file format, but I haven't seen any for the reverse situation.

Comment: Does your gdal support writing (w) to JP2, you can check with `gdalinfo --formats`

Comment: This is what I see: ```JP2OpenJPEG -raster,vector- (rwv): JPEG-2000 driver based on OpenJPEG library```. I'm guessing the w in the "rwv" means I can write?

Comment: It does not need to be any more complicated than `gdal_translate -of JP2OpenJPEG <input file>.jpg <output file>.jp2)`. Gdal_translate accepts only one file as an input if your original command tried to do that. But maybe you should read also https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Is there a way to use the .jgw file (or the information of the .jgw file itself) when using gdalbuildvrt? I see that the .jgw file only contains a few numbers, so I'm guessing I can just access them and then set the parameters in ```gdalbuildvrt``` to them? And after creating the VRT, I'm guessing I can make it into a .jp2 using ```gdal_translate -of JP2OpenJPEG <input file>.vrt <output file>.jp2)```